# Anyone know of a Yii extension or method for displaying model relations and table schema (including keys and comments) as a flowchart?

Tags: yii, model, schema, visualization, yii-relations

I can't seem to find any extension/module/etc that does this nicely.

You can access the column metadata as follows, but I want a good way to display it as a flowchart or hypergraph in a model's index.

```
$m=new MyModel; 
Yii::log(CVarDumper::dumpAsString($m->tableSchema->columns),'warning');
```

// echo $m->toJSON(); // uses json behavior, will give this to a js flowchart to show the schema

Comment: Sorry, but unfortunately the "Yii" does not possess any extension that manages it yet.

Comment: You could try using the CTreeView and a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is one tool in phpmyadmin called designer. its written in PHP and really draw a nice data model from database. you should refer that code.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want, but have you had a look at [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/) yet? Experience with it is somewhat [mixed](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/13004-what-is-your-experience-with-mysql-workbench/), but I find it great to keep an overview of databases.